# ¿Se puede implementar una opción para que el usuario guarde preguntas y respuestas favoritas?

Tags: discusión, soporte

Hay preguntas y respuestas que me resultan muy interesantes, me pregunto, si de puede implementar una opciòn para que los usuarios guardemos preguntas y respuestas favoritas, de manera que puedan ser conservadas para uso posterior o inmediato.

Comment: Solo las preguntas tienen esa opción, al marcarlas ya "podrías" estar considerando como favorito sus respuestas. =)

Comment: @Davlio No estoy de acuerdo. Hay muchas preguntas cuyo título y formulación riñen con el lenguaje e incluso con el sentido común. Y no obstante, han recibido respuestas interesantes, útiles y profundas que quedan ahogadas por el océano de incoherencia conformado por aquellos. Más aún, sus títulos hacen casi imposible llegar a encontrar las respuestas si se llega a pensar al leerlos. De modo que marcar la pregunta, para llorar al leerla cuando se quiera regresar a la respuesta y no entender que está en relación con lo buscado, carece de sentido.